# number formatin in javascript (cant be a function)

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

Im having an issue when trying to format a number in my code, i cant make it looks like "1.000,00", ive searched some codes, but i only found functions, and i cant use functions since my variable (valor) already is inside a function.

So, can someone help me do a code (not a function) to format my variable (valor) from 1000 to 1.000,00 ?

Thanks so much for your patience

Comment: i think its possible to call a function within another function

Comment: You can still use a function even though your variable is already in a function.  Trust me, if your requirements for any functionality are that it can't be a function, you will be unable to develop any software.

Comment: you can have functions within functions as well
function a()
{
 alert('x');
 function b()
 {
 }
 b();
}

Comment: @user1161318 spot on! You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @akuhn: Posted as an answer :)

Comment: on nice, thanks everybody, gonna try doing a function inside then, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a function even though your variable is already in a function. Trust me, if your requirements for any functionality are that it can't be a function, you will be unable to develop any software.

Comment: Oh i see, thanks, im pretty new to programming, didnt know that, thanks again !